# docker-compose pull gives either a gpg error or a permissions error when I attempt to use it with or without sudo

Tags: docker-compose, gnupg

everyone.
I hope that someone can help to answer my question.
I am joining a project in which I have to use various docker containers.  I was told that I just needed to use docker-compose to pull down all the necessary containers.  I tried this, and got two different errors, based on whether I used sudo or not.  My machine is Ubuntu bionic beaver 18.04.4LTS
I have docker-engine installed according to the installation instructions for Bionic on the github page, and docker-compose is likewise installed according to its instructions.  I did not create a "docker" group since I have sudo access.

We have two repos that I have to log in to before I can do anything.  In order to prevent my passwords from being stored unencrypted in config.json, I followed this guide to set up a secure credential store:
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-setup-secure-credential-storage-for-docker/

However, rather than asking me for the password and/or passphrase mentioned in this article, the login process makes me enter the actual passwords to the repos.  So, the secure credential store may not be working, which might be causing the problem.

At any rate, once I log in and the two commands show login succeeded, I then try to do a
docker-compose pull
on the repos.  When I do
sudo docker-compose pull
I get this final error:
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-pass exited with "exit status 2: gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/myuser/.gnupg'\ngpg: decryption failed: No secret key".')
an ls of the .gnupg directory is
myuser@myhost$ ls -lA ~ | grep gnupg
drwx------  4 myuser myuser   226 Feb  9 13:35 .gnupg

gpg --list-secret-keys shows my keypair when I run it as myuser.

I am assuming that what is happening is that because I am running as sudo the user trying to access this directory is root, not myuser, and so it is failing.  However, if I leave off the sudo
docker-compose pull
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

I am guessing that this is because my normal user doesn't have the ability to connect to the docker daemon's Unix socket.

So, how do I make these play together?  Is the answer to add a docker group so that the command still runs as myuser and not as root? or is there another way to do this?

Also, why is my credential store not asking me for the password set by docker-credential-pass or the GPG passphrase?  I suspect these two are related.  Perhaps the pull is trying to send my authentication tokens over again and can't because it doesn't have access to the secure credentials store.

All of the above are guesses.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

Thanking you in advance,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to follow up with a solution to this question that worked for me.

Firstly, you need to add your user to the docker group that was created during docker-engine's installation.
sudo usermod --append --groups docker your_user_name

Because I had already used sudo to try this, there were a few files that ended up being created by root.
So, you have to chown a few things.
sudo chown your_user_name:your_group_name ~/.docker/config.json
Note that for the group name I used
docker
but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Then, there were files inside the ~/.password-store directory that needed to be changed.
sudo chown -R your_user_name:your_group_name ~/.password-store

Most of these files are already owned by you, but the recorded credentials are not.

Then, the magic that fixed it all. From
https://ask.csdn.net/questions/5153956
you have to do this.
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)

and it is this last that makes gpg work.
Then, you can log in to your repos if you have to without using sudo
docker login -u repo_user_name your_repo_host
and then log in with your repo password.
Note that I don't know why you have to use the repo password instead of using the stored credentials.
Once you log in, you should be able to do a
docker-compose pull
without sudo
from the directory where you want the containers to be placed.

Note that you will probably have to provide your GPG passphrase at first.  I'm not sure about this because I had already unlocked the key by following the steps in the above link to check to see if docker-credential-pass had the right credential store password stored.
and that should do it.

Comment: I apologize for the look of this answer.  When I wrote it, the commands were on lines by themselves, but in the answer they are all squashed together with the text.  I'm not sure what happened there.